# Add product in wishlist via soap api in magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I am working on Magento SOAP api and i have created all api like add products in add to cart, check out but there is no api for magento soap api for add products in wishlist, list of my wish list and delete wish list. I have checked the Magento soap api but not found any relatively api.

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not have an API for wishlist. It can be created by following the Instructions on "how to create custom API" and using the Models used by the Frontend.